# Creating a border based on a data value around a custom bullet in amcharts?

Tags: amcharts

I want to create a border around my custom bullet in AMCharts. The idea is that the border will be a different color based on some value in my data. This is my code right now:

```
graphs: [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 50,
    "customBullet": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/star.png?x",
    "bulletBorderColor": "#00ff00" ,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 10,
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "id": "AmGraph",
    "title": "graph",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "value",
    "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1"
  }]
```

It looks as if having a custom bullet overrides the border thickness, color, and alpha. Is there a way around this? The border doesn't have to match the shape of the contents of the picture, obviously, just along the edge.

New development:
I was able to figure out how to add a custom class to each bullet, but I am having trouble modifying the css to make the border appear. More often then not, the whole image disappears. Any suggestions on how to create a border around this?

```
<g transform="translate(173,27) scale(1)" aria-label="graph category" class="amcharts-graph-bullet CustomClass" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1"></g>
```

I tried adding

```
style="stroke: #0000ff; stroke-width: 4px;"
```

but to no effect at all.

Comment: If you use a custom bullet, you're using an external file, which overrides the existing bullet completly. You have to make your changes on the source of the bullet. In your case, make a copy of the star.png, increase its borders, host it on your server and refer to this file in your chart.

Comment: That would be my last resort. I would rather not have to download the images onto the server because of space considerations, but yes, that is an option, I suppose.

Comment: If you would use svg files as bullets, you could tweak them with css. Or you could download them, which should be smaller than saving pngs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @gerric suggestion of using SVG bullets, here's another workaround.

Using two overlaid graphs: 1 your regular graph with PNG bullets; 2 - transparent graph with just the bullet outline:

```
"graphs": [{
  "bullet": "round",
  "bulletSize": 50,
  "customBullet": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/star.png?x",
  "bulletBorderColor": "#00ff00",
  "bulletBorderThickness": 10,
  "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
  "id": "AmGraph",
  "title": "graph",
  "type": "smoothedLine",
  "valueField": "value",
  "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1"
}, {
  "bullet": "round",
  "bulletSize": 50,
  "bulletBorderColor": "#00ff00",
  "bulletAlpha": 0,
  "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
  "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
  "valueField": "value",
  "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1",
  "lineAlpha": 0,
  "balloonText": "",
  "visibleInLegend": false
}]
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "date": "2009-10-02",
    "value": 5
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-03",
    "value": 15
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-04",
    "value": 13
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-05",
    "value": 17
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-06",
    "value": 15
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-09",
    "value": 19
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-10",
    "value": 21
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-11",
    "value": 20
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-12",
    "value": 20
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-13",
    "value": 19
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-16",
    "value": 25
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-17",
    "value": 24
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-18",
    "value": 26
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-19",
    "value": 27
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-20",
    "value": 25
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-23",
    "value": 29
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-24",
    "value": 28
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-25",
    "value": 30
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-26",
    "value": 72,
    "customBullet": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/redstar.png"
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-27",
    "value": 43
  }, {
    "date": "2009-10-30",
    "value": 31
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "dashLength": 4,
    "position": "left"
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 50,
    "customBullet": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/star.png?x",
    "bulletBorderColor": "#00ff00",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 10,
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "id": "AmGraph",
    "title": "graph",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": "value",
    "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1"
  }, {
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletSize": 50,
    "bulletBorderColor": "#00ff00",
    "bulletAlpha": 0,
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "valueField": "value",
    "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1",
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "balloonText": "",
    "visibleInLegend": false
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    //"graphBulletSize": 1,
    "zoomable": false,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
  },
  "autoMargins": false,
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "categoryField": "date",
  "valueScrollbar": {
    "offset": 30
  },
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "inside": true,
    "tickLength": 0
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: How to display bullet on min value of y-axis or how to find min value of y-axis ?